# mysql trigger after update is not working

Tags: mysql, sql

This trigger is supposed to update the free rooms available for a hospital.When a patient leaves the trigger adds one more free room.But it just doesn't work and I really cannot understand why.I use these tables for this trigger:

```
create table Incidents
(primary key(incident_code),
foreign key(patient_code) references Patients(patient_code)on delete cascade on update cascade,
foreign key(section_code) references Sections(section_code)on delete cascade on update cascade,
foreign key(doctor_code) references Doctors(doctor_code)on delete cascade on update cascade,
incident_code int unsigned,
patient_code int unsigned,
section_code int unsigned,
doctor_code int unsigned,
import_day date not null,
export_day date,
incident_value real not null
check(datediff(export_day,import_day)>-1));

(primary key(section_code),
section_code int unsigned,
section_name varchar(30) not null,
total_rooms int not null,
free_rooms int not null
check(total_rooms>=free_rooms));
```

this is the triggers code:

```
delimiter @
create trigger FreeRooms1
after update on incidents
for each row
begin
 if (old.export_day=null and new.export_day != null)
 then
   update sections
   set free_rooms = free_rooms + 1   
   where sections.section_code = incidents.section_code;
 end if;
end;
@
```

And this is how I try to activate it:

```
update incidents
set export_day = '2013/12/24'
where incident_code = 2;

select section_code,section_name,free_rooms
from sections;
```

I tried many variations for the trigger but any change I make doesn't make work.Any help?
Sorry if my question seems bad I am fairly new to mySQL and I can't find an answer anywhere.

Comment: You can't test for `NULL` using `=` or `!=` you need to use `if old.export_day is null and new.export_day is not null`

Comment: Thank you,too.I never came across this specific syntax and would never have found it without your help.

Comment: Check the manual: it's all documented there: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use:

```
delimiter @
create trigger FreeRooms1
after update on incidents
for each row
begin
 if (old.export_day IS NULL and new.export_day IS NOT NULL)
 then
   update sections
   set free_rooms = free_rooms + 1   
   where sections.section_code = NEW.section_code;
 end if;
end;
@
```

and reference the new row.

Comment: Thank you it was your answer combined with this :
old.export_day=null and new.export_day != null 
which should be :
old.export_day is null and new.export_day is not null

I didn't realise that it I had to use new on section code because I only changed the export_day.But it seems that it updates the whole row anyway.